# Can I add images to the main field of my question?

Tags: support, images

Can I add images to the main field of my question? I mean in such way so that they are seen in it. Or I can only add links to those images?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure you can, click the image icon in the editor ([image: icon]) when you're writing your question - it's the one next to the code block icon. ([image: icon])

You'll need a reputation of [at least 10](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/new-user) to add images.

Comment: Thanks, Dominic! How did I on earth not notice that?!!!!

Comment: @John, added the minimum reputation required.

Comment: Why di we need rep to do this?

Comment: @Cole to prevent spammers from spamming us with pictures and to reduce the load on the image hosting servers. New users can post just a link to the picture and high rep users will integrate the picture into the post. It's also explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/new-user) under "Why are restrictions placed on new users?".

Comment: To use an image, you just add a `!` before the link. Not that hard. What should be done is prevent users with <10 rep from _adding_ images at all. As in, no adding ![ to a post... (An image doesn't have to be from the stack imgr...)