# Adding images to questions

Tags: support, images

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post)

I want to know how to place an image in a question. I have a screenshot file which is the output of my code. I want to show that image in my question from my local file system. I tried using the `<img>` tag, but it is asking me for a URL for the image.

Comment: see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28525/how-do-i-post-a-screenshot-on-stack-overflow and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32883/can-i-add-images-to-the-main-field-of-my-question

Answer (score 1):

Upload your image to a free image hosting site and then specify the url with  tag.
ex: tinypic.com or imageshack.us

Answer (score -1):

Upload it to a image hoster and use it like a link, Reference is here:

[Editing Help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: I hate that since you never know if they're going to be around long-term. I'd prefer ASCII art myself.